# How can I change the handling of my terminal background color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using VSCode terminal.
But when I type 'yarn start', the background color gets changed to white.
I don't want my terminal background color changed.

So how can I change this mis-behaviour?  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElhhW.png)

Comment: i'm afraid that this question is off-topic

Comment: (@user135142: I see a question about a tool used by programmers to handle source code - can you point out what makes you think ["off-topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?)

Comment: It is on-topic.

Comment: @greybeard , shouldn't it be posted in software recommendations stackexchange?

Comment: (@user135142: I'm confident this question is on topic here as is. I think it would be [on-topic over there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have a look at the tags on each site and how many questions similar to the above have been asked this year, and usefully answered.)